# Node.js: How to better manage router and authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, router

In my `node.js` code, I have lot router and authentication to manage, like:

```
app.get('/', fn);
app.get('/admin', checkAccess, fn);
app.get('/blog', checkAccess, fn);
```

may be the router number coule be dozen or more,

how can I manage them better?

Is there a manage module? or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple callbacks, as per your example, or a simple decorator pattern.

**Multiple callbacks**

```
function checkAccess(req, res) {
    // check for access
    if (!access) {
        res.send(403);
    }
}

app.get('/', fn);
app.get('/admin', checkAccess, fn);
app.get('/blog', checkAccess, fn);
```

**Simple decorator pattern**

```
function requiresAccess(fn) {
    return function (req, res) {
        // check for access
        if (access) {
          fn(req, res);
        } else {
          res.send(403);
        }
    }
}

app.get('/', fn);
app.get('/admin', requiresAccess(fn));
app.get('/blog', requiresAccess(fn));
```